# asp.net page compilation process

Tags: asp.net, compilation

I'm looking for detailed technical information on the compilation process for aspx pages and vs2008.  Recently I have been learning about controlbuilders and pageparserfilters.  I have downloaded some code to clean out extra white spaces in my html in order to make the pages smaller.  The code works great, but I don't understand WHY it works.  I need to learn more about the page compilation process.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Which code did you download? Please provide a url to the source. This might be of interest to others as well.

Comment: Here is the link to the site for cleaning up whitespace in aspx pages.  http://omari-o.blogspot.com/2009/09/aspnet-white-space-cleaning-with-no.html