# ASP .NET Just in time

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, asp-classic

Does for every http request ASP .NET page compiled just in time (JITting) or when the page is first time requested, or when application startups?

I can't find any resource about that.

Comment: It's a good question but I can't believe it hasn't been asked before - have you searched previous questions?

Comment: Is the asp classic tag necessary and correct?

Comment: Perhaps [this will help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325174/asp-net-page-compilation-process) specifically the [link to here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Comment: Take a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398860(v=vs.100).aspx, if you are using .net 4, then take a look here too http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ASP.NET automatically compiles your application code and any dependent resources the first time a user requests a resource from the Web site.

[ASP.NET Compilation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178466%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> By default, ASP.NET Web pages and code files are compiled dynamically when users first request a resource, such as an ASP.NET page (.aspx file), from a Web site. After pages and code files have been compiled the first time, the compiled resources are cached, so that subsequent requests to the same page are extremely efficient.

[Understanding ASP.NET Dynamic Compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms366723)

Answer (score 1):

By default first request for each page - see [Understanding ASP.NET Dynamic compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  It will then recompile first time the page is requested after it has changed.

You can, however, specify precompilation options in your config file

Answer (score 1):

You can test it by yourself.

Create *mypage.aspx* in *C:\inetpub\wwwroot* directory and write this:

```
<%@ Page language="C#" debug="true" %>
<html>
<head></head>
<%= this.GetType().Assembly.Location %>
</html>
```

When you open it in browser you will get something like this:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\26676eb7\92c7e946\App_Web_ip00zfkv.dll

go to that address and you will see generated files (Note that because *debug=true* is specified in *Page* directive, source code is not deleted).

You can create another request (simply refresh page) and you can see *dll* name is not changed. But if you change something in *mypage.aspx* file, than new *dll* will be generated with different name.